# 220 hertz sine doesn't sound correct

Tags: objective-c, avaudioengine

I have the following Objective-C code that generates a 220hz tone, however, it doesn't sound like other 220hz tones, for example Wikipedia has a 220 tone here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:220_Hz_sine_wave.ogg that sounds very low, mine sounds really high pitched in comparison...any ideas?

```
- (void)render:(AVAudioPCMBuffer *)bufferInput frequency:(float)frequency amplitude:(float)amplitude
{
    const int channels = 2;
    int inNumberFrames = bufferInput.frameLength;
    float *const *floatChannelData = bufferInput.floatChannelData;

    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames ; i ++) {
        float theta = frequency * i * 2.0 * M_PI / 44100;
        float value = sinf(theta);
        for (int channelNumber = 0; channelNumber < channels ; channelNumber++) {
            float * const channelBuffer = floatChannelData[channelNumber];
            channelBuffer[i] = value * amplitude;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the format of your buffer? Are you certain the sample rate is 44.1kHz? Is `inNumberFrames` what you expect it to be (it is possible for `frameLength` to be less than `frameCapacity`). You might compare to my version (which I don't claim is perfect, but is another example and "sounds right"): https://github.com/rnapier/ToneGen/blob/master/ToneGen/SineWaveAudioBuffer.swift

Comment: ah! It seems the difference was the frame length, mine was far too short: 100, I bumped it to 400 and it sounds much much better! Thanks!